# Objective-C iOS 7.0 iAd SpriteKit landscape mode appears wrong when canDisplayBannerAds is set to YES

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, iad

I am trying to create an app with SpriteKit that will support landscape mode only (Left and Right Landscape) as well as integrate iAd. The app runs fine, but once I set `self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES`, the orientation is thrown off. Note that the ad appears fine, but the "originalContentView" is sideways (90 degrees) from the landscape orientation.

This is what the view (correctly) looks like with `canDisplayBannerAds=NO`

[image: Correct view orientation]

This is what the view (incorrectly) looks like with `canDisplayBannerAds=YES`

[image: Incorrect view orientation]

I have uploaded a sample project [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/l8co0u2m42q16uj/AdTest.zip) with the scenario setup. Inside `AdTestViewController.m` on line 38 is where you can comment out the `self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;` to see the corrected view.

Am I doing something wrong or is this an issue on Apple's side? Either way, what would be the best work around?

Comment: can you post your supportedInterfaceOrientations in ViewController.m ?

Comment: @Ilario Thanks for your comment. I uploaded the sample project in the link above ([here it is as well])http://www.mediafire.com/download/l8co0u2m42q16uj/AdTest.zip) ), but here is the code:

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
}

Comment: if you only support landscape mode try to replace all this code with : return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

Comment: @Ilario I gave it a try in both the sample project (posted above) and my real project - it didnt work. The same outcome happens (the 2nd picture above). Any other suggestions would be great. Thanks again for the time and help.